# crypto++ Sending IV to another Function but i get an error: StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found

Tags: c++, crypto++

Test Program to Encrypt using crypto++, then it sends the iv and message as IV::EncryptedMessage.

I am able to encrypt but get a padding error #7 when decrypting, I've searched for hours but can't find anyway to pass a std::string IV to crypto++.

I believe my error is in the `decc` function, where I use hexdecode?

```
string encc(string plain) {
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;


    SecByteBlock iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    std::string sKey = "UltraSecretKeyPhrase";
    SecByteBlock key((const unsigned char*)(sKey.data()), sKey.size());
    prng.GenerateBlock(iv, iv.size());
    std::string cipher, recovered;

    try
    {
        CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
        e.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv);

        StringSource s(plain, true,
            new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
                new StringSink(cipher)
            ) 
        ); 
    }
    catch (const Exception& e)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    string ciphertxt, ivString;

    HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));
    encoder.Detach(new StringSink(ivString));
    encoder.Put(iv, iv.size());
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    encoder.Detach(new StringSink(ciphertxt));
    encoder.Put((const byte*)&cipher[0], cipher.size());
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    string toSend = ivString + "::" + ciphertxt;
    return toSend;
}

string decc(string toDec) {
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    std::string sKey = "UltraSecretKeyPhrase";
    SecByteBlock key((const unsigned char*)(sKey.data()), sKey.size());
    
    
    std::string recovered;
    string str1 = "::";

   
    size_t found = toDec.find(str1);
    if (found != string::npos) {

        std::string sIv = toDec.substr(0, found);
        std::string encMessage = toDec.substr(found + 2, toDec.length());
        
        cout << endl << "IV: " << sIv << endl << "Encoded Msg: " << encMessage << endl;
        
        string iv;
        HexDecoder decoder;

        decoder.Attach(new StringSink(iv));
        decoder.Put((byte*)sIv.data(), sIv.size());
        decoder.MessageEnd();
        try
        {
            CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;
            d.SetKeyWithIV(key.data(), key.size(), (byte *)iv.data(), AES::BLOCKSIZE);

            StringSource s(encMessage, true,
                new StreamTransformationFilter(d,
                    new StringSink(recovered)
                )
            );
            return recovered;
        }
        catch (const Exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else return NULL;
}

int main(){
    string hh = encc("this is encoded");
    cout << hh << endl;
    string gg = decc(hh);
    cout << gg << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Just can't seem to use the right words for google :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Decoded the hex of the IV but never the actual encrypted message. Of course I seen it after I posted smh...

This is a functional example of crypto++ encode and decode functions for anyone looking for it.

```
string encc(string plain) {
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;


    SecByteBlock iv(AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    std::string sKey = "UltraSecretKeyPhrase";
    SecByteBlock key((const unsigned char*)(sKey.data()), sKey.size());
    prng.GenerateBlock(iv, iv.size());
    std::string cipher, recovered;

    try
    {
        CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
        e.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv);

        StringSource s(plain, true,
            new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
                new StringSink(cipher)
            ) 
        ); 
    }
    catch (const Exception& e)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    string ciphertxt, ivString;

    HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));
    encoder.Detach(new StringSink(ivString));
    encoder.Put(iv, iv.size());
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    encoder.Detach(new StringSink(ciphertxt));
    encoder.Put((const byte*)&cipher[0], cipher.size());
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    string toSend = ivString + "::" + ciphertxt;
    return toSend;
}

string decc(string toDec) {
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    std::string sKey = "UltraSecretKeyPhrase";
    SecByteBlock key((const unsigned char*)(sKey.data()), sKey.size());
    
    
    std::string recovered;
    string str1 = "::";

   
    size_t found = toDec.find(str1);
    if (found != string::npos) {

        std::string sIv = toDec.substr(0, found);
        std::string encMessageHex = toDec.substr(found + 2);
        
        cout << endl << "IV: " << sIv << endl << "Encoded Msg: " << encMessageHex << endl;
        
        string iv, encMessage;
        HexDecoder decoder, msgDecoder;

        decoder.Attach(new StringSink(iv));
        decoder.Put((byte*)sIv.data(), sIv.size());
        decoder.MessageEnd();
        // Forgot to decode encrypted message hex. added here
        decoder.Attach(new StringSink(encMessage));
        decoder.Put((byte*)encMessageHex.data(), encMessageHex.size());
        decoder.MessageEnd();
        try
        {
            CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;
            d.SetKeyWithIV(key.data(), key.size(), (byte *)iv.data(), AES::BLOCKSIZE);

            StringSource s(encMessage, true,
                new StreamTransformationFilter(d,
                    new StringSink(recovered)
                )
            );
            return recovered;
        }
        catch (const Exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else return NULL;
}

int main(){
    string hh = encc("this is encoded");
    cout << hh << endl;
    string gg = decc(hh);
    cout << gg << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice that you found your bug, up-voted!

Answer (score 1):

You have a decoding bug, instead of `toDec.substr(found + 2, toDec.length())` you should write `toDec.substr(found + 2, toDec.length() - (found + 2))`, because [.substr()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) accepts number of symbols, not the end-position.

Maybe there are other bugs, but this definitely will break decoding process due to having garbarge inside encrypted message.

You may also just use `toDec.substr(found + 2)`, i.e. don't specify the count, if second param is not specified then substring is taken till the very end of string.

Comment: Mmm. The program does ```cout``` the encoded message fine. You think there's some trailing rubbish after? I'll boot the pc back up and have a look.

Comment: It still works with length as length() definition is _The number of bytes in the string_. But +1 for `toDec.substr(found + 2)`

Comment: @Comet No it doesn't work with `.lenth()` because you have to provide not the total string length, but number of chars in final substring, in other words if your string length is 15 and you do `s.substr(5, s.length())` then substr returns substring of length 15, but you actually want length 10 result, so second param is number of chars in returned substring, it is not the number of chars in a string, in other words to return string and certain `offset` and when string length is `.length()` then you have to do `s.substr(offset, s.length() - offset)`, the way you do now gives Undefined Behaviour

Comment: @Comet Sorry, it is not an undefined behaviour, it appears that `.substr()` cuts it output if it exceeds string, but still it is nice to write `s.substr(offset, s.length() - offset)` or even better `s.substr(offset)` instead of `s.substr(offset, s.length())`. Even if it appeared to be not undefined behaviour then still it may misslead someone.

Comment: your right. It would be better to get into that habit and avoid bugs. Cheers